# Why do I get 'this is undefined' in my Octane component methods?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-3, ember-octane

I'm writing some Octane-style components in Ember v3.13, together with the `{{did-insert}}` [ember-render-modifier](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-render-modifiers). However, when the function tied to `did-insert` is called, I get `TypeError: this is undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my component template:

```
<div class="cardhost-monaco-container" {{did-insert this.renderEditor}}></div>
```

And here's the component's JavaScript class:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';


export default class CodeEditor extends Component {
  renderEditor(el) {
    console.log(this.args.code)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Methods that are used as actions in templates need to be decorated with `@action` to have correct `this`-context:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class CodeEditor extends Component {
  @action
  renderEditor(el) {
    console.log(this.args.code)
  }
}
```

The action decorator binds the component context to the method. This is described in more detail in the [API docs for `action`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject/action).

Comment: "Any time" is way to broad. Only method that are used as actions in templates need to be decorated with `@action` to have correct `this`-context. It's discussed more in detail in [API docs](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.14/functions/@ember%2Fobject/action).

Comment: Thanks @jelhan, I have updated it to include your suggestion!